# Prove that $\sum _{k=0}^n \left(\sum _{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j}\right)^3=\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) 8^n-\frac{3}{4} n 2^n \binom{2 n}{n}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Define $$S(m,n):=\sum _{k=0}^n \left(\sum _{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j}\right)^m$$

Then $S(1,n)$ is trivial and by elementary manipulations $S(2,n)=\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) 4^n-\frac{1}{2} n \binom{2 n}{n}$.

---

The first problem: How to prove $S(3,n)=\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) 8^n-\frac{3}{4} n 2^n \binom{2 n}{n}$ as mentioned by Foreman?

The second problem: Is there a general closed-form for $S(m,n)$? According to OEIS the answer is probably no, so a recurrence formula on $m$ is also welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add how have you came accross this sum?

Comment: For $m=3$ we have$$S(3,n)=(n+2)\cdot 2^{3n-1}-3n\cdot 2^{n-2}\cdot\binom{2n}{n}$$A closed form doesn't seem to be known for $m\gt3$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A294435

Comment: @雄凤山: Interesting post, interesting references. (+1) done yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here we follow closely the proof provided in *[this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9500086C?via%3Dihub)*
> by M. Hirschhorn and show
> \begin{align*}
> S(3,n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}\right)^3=(n+2)2^{3n-1}-3\cdot2^{n-2}n\binom{2n}{n}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We  denote with $A_k=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}$  and  have  to show $S(3,n)=\sum_{k=0}^nA_k^3$.  We  need two intermediate results which are interesting by its own and which are shown at the end of this post:

The following is valid for $0\leq k\leq n-1$:

\begin{align*}
A_k+A_{n-1-k}&=2^n\tag{2}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_kA_{n-1-k}&=\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S(3,n)}&=\sum_{k=0}^nA_k^3\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(A_k^3+A_{n-1-k}^3\right)+A_n^3\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(A_k+A_{n-k+1}\right)\left(A_k^2-A_kA_{n-1-k}+A_{n-1-k}^2\right)+A_n^3\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^n\left(A_k^2-A_kA_{n-1-k}+A_{n-1-k}^2\right)+A_n^3\tag{6}\\
> &=2^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_k^2-2^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_kA_{n-1-k}+2^nA_n^2\tag{7}\\
> &=2^nS(2,n)-n2^{n-2}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{8}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(n+2)2^{3n-1}-3\cdot2^{n-2}n\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (4) we use the symmetry $\sum_{k=0}^nA_k^3=\sum_{k=0}^{n}A_{n-k}^3$.
- In (5) we apply $x^3-y^3=(x-y)\left(x^2-xy+y^2\right)$.
- In (6) we use the identity from (2).
- In (7) we use again the symmetry as we did in (4).
- In (8) we use the identity from (3) and write $S(2,n)=\sum_{k=0}^nA_k^2$.
- In (9) we use the result $S(2,n)=(n+2)2^{2n-1}-\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$.

> **Proof of (2):**
>
> We have
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A_k+A_{n-1-k}}&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{j}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{k+1+k}\tag{10}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}+\sum_{j=k+1}^n\binom{n}{j}\tag{11}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^n}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (2) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (10) we change the order of summation in the second sum $j\to n-1-k-j$ and use the identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (11) we shift the index in the second sum to start with $k+1$.

> **Proof of (3):**
>
> We have
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}}\color{blue}{A_kA_{n-1-k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{l}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{n}{j}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1-k}\binom{n}{k+1+l}\tag{12}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}\sum_{l=k+1}^{n}\binom{n}{l}\tag{13}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{l=j+1}^{n}\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=j}^{l-1}1\tag{14}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq j<l\leq n}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{l}(l-j)\tag{15}\\
> &=\sum_{q=1}^nq\sum_{j=0}^{n-q}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{q+j}\tag{16}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^nq\sum_{j=0}^{n-q}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{n-q-j}\tag{17}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^nq\binom{2n}{n+q}\tag{18}\\
> &=n\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{2n-1}{n+q-1}-n\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{2n-1}{n+q}\tag{19}\\
> &=n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\tag{20}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{21}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (12) we change the order of summation $l\to n-1-k-l$ and we use the identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (13) we exchange the two left-most sums respecting the index region $0\leq j\leq k\leq n-1$ and factor out $\binom{n}{j}$.
- In (14) we exchange the two right-most sums respecting the index region $j\leq k<l\leq n$ and factor out $\binom{n}{l}$.
- In (15) we simplify and write the index region somewhat more conveniently.
- In (16) we substitute $q=l-j$.
- In (17) we apply the identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (18) we apply *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*.
- In (19) we write $q\binom{2n}{n+q}=(n+q-n)\binom{2n}{n+q}$ and apply the identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p-1}{q}+\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (20) we use the telescoping property of the sums.
- In (21) we use the identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.

> *Note:* In the cited paper we also find that the reduction from $S(3,n)$ to $S(2,n)$ in (8) can be generalized to derive a recurrence relation for $S(m,n)$. We have for $m\geq 1$:
> \begin{align*}
> S(2m,n)&=\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m}{k}2^{kn}S(2m-k,n)+(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_k^mA_{n-1-k}^m\\
> S(2m+1,n)&=\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m}{k}2^{kn}S(2m+1-k,n)+(-1)^m2^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A_k^mA_{n-1-k}^m\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: @雄凤山: Many thanks for your nice comment.